# How to add multiple coloring pages in basic Android drawing app?

Tags: android, canvas

I am completely new here and to developing apps. I following a basic tutorial:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-drawing-app-interface-creation--mobile-19021

It has three parts to the tutorial. But eventually you have an app that can draw with multiple colors, can erase, save, change the brush size and start with a new canvas.

My aim is to add an option for the user to choose a background for the canvas. I have already set a drawable to be the background for the canvas currently used. So that the kids can "color in". I now want to add a button which lets that change the background of the canvas. I would like to let them choose between 9 different "templates"

As the app has many different pieces of code, and i dont know exactly which one to paste here, please go to the tutorial page to see all the code that was used. OR just ask me which part to paste in here.

Sorry if I am being unclear or vague, but im really an early beginner.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Hey Hi @yususfh i am facing exactly same problem did you find any solution

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the onDraw method of your custom view for coloring in so that, before it draws the background drawable you have assigned, it fills itself with the color the child has selected and then change your drawable so that it is transparent apart from a hollow sketch of the object they are coloring in.
You can also work in layers by separating the background color, the drawable and the childs scribbles in three views on top of each other and combine them only when you come to save the finished work.